# is there limit on concurrent connection number when browser downloading html resources?

Tags: html, concurrency, connection

Generally, in order to speed up overwhole loading, browser would open serval concurrent connection to download the resource files parallelly.

I want to know, for a certain browser, is there  a limit on the concurrent connection number?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide much detail only some general pointers:

The HTTP standard defines a connection limit per client<->server.
In Windows for example there is a registry setting which can be used to change that... Not all browsers/browsers versions and/or OS/OS versions implement the standard-defined limit(s) and/or take the registry setting into account...

Answer (score 0):

It's browser dependent.

For example,
 FireFox has a default of 30 global max, and 15 per server, which can be increased to 65535.

FAQs:_About:config_Entries">http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:*FAQs*:_About:config_Entries

And apparently Chrome's limits are lower (6) with no ability to configure.

Google for more information